# Getting nearest date that is after the specified date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, strtotime

I have several date(strtotime) in a input value and want the nearest date that is after the specified date(my date) with jQuery or javascript. what do i do?

```
<input id="DateBox" value="1481691600,1482037200,1482642000">
```

**my date:**

```
1481778000 => (2016-12-15)
```

**several date(strtotime):**

```
1481691600 => (2016-12-14)
1482037200 => (2016-12-18)
1482642000 => (2016-12-25)
```

**return:**

```
1482037200 => (2016-12-18)
```

Comment: What is "strtotime"?

Comment: strtotime in php, : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: I do not know about it.

Comment: You don't want the nearest date; you want the nearest date **that is after the specified date**.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you close to what you need. Essentially you need to iterate over every value and compare it to your current date, storing the best value as you go. Pardon me if any of my syntax is a tad off.

```
current_date = 1481778000;
// Get our values as an array.
var all_values = jQuery('#DateBox').val().split(',');
// Track our current value and difference.
var current_val = -1;
var current_diff = -1;
jQuery.each(all_values, function(index, value) {
    if(current_val == -1) {
        // First value is automatically the best guess.
        current_val = value;
        current_diff = Math.abs(current_date - value);
    } else {
        // Compare against our current best guess.
        if(Math.abs(current_date - value) < current_diff)
            current_val = value;
    }
});
//We have our value.
console.log("Correct Value", current_val);
```

Comment: With the caveat that an input with no value will return a value of -1.

Comment: tnx, but this give me result `Correct Value 1481691600`, In case that the nearest date to `1481778000 => (2016-12-15)` is : `1482037200 => (2016-12-18)` . see:https://jsfiddle.net/gmmn4erq/

Comment: i want the nearest date that is after the specified date(my date).

Comment: Ah, my apologies. In that case you would just remove the absolute values.  You may need to flip the subtraction to this as well: `value - current_date`. Just fiddle with it a tad and i'm sure you can massage out what you need. I have faith in you :P

Comment: but i trying as it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/gmmn4erq/3/ please give me.

Comment: You just need to ignore cases that are before you current date.
https://jsfiddle.net/wf7bof7h/